# Find paths covering all nodes in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How do we find out paths in neo4j which will cover all the selected set of nodes.

This will be used for solving a tsp of sorts. to find path which covers all the given set of cities, later will sort on the basis of total distance covered by the path.

Comment: Check this related question - you might consider using an MST algorithm to find a path that touches everything; that's what they do.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25609717/how-to-use-neo4j-for-finding-minimum-spanning-tree

Answer (score 1):

You can find all paths between two nodes like this.

```
match p=(:startNode)-->(:endNode)
return p;
```

or you can try like

```
match p=(:startNode)-->(:endNode)
return nodes(p) as node, relationships(p) as  rels
```

You can get all paths like this

```
match p = ()-->()
return p
limit 100 // Apply limit according to nodes
```

Comment: Find path which covers all nodes. A single path which will cover all the nodes. I am trying to solve a tsp using neo4j.

Comment: @Ferventum Edited. Is that what you need ??

Comment: I want to solve a travelling salesman problem by finding Hamiltonian paths in the data. For that I need to find **paths which cover all the nodes**

Comment: -[r*]- is to be used for multiple nodes. "-->" is for relationship.